# Android: new mp3 files not found in update version of play store

Tags: android, file-io, resources, mp3

I have an application in play store that have mp3 files in **raw** directory. In the version 1 of this app, all the mp3 files found and can play with MediaPlayer. Later i add some mp3 files than release new version on Play Store, after i update on my device( or i install on fresh device) the new mp3 files not found. but when i run with android studio, the new files is found. Could anyone help me? the point is the mp3 files on raw directory is not found after the 1st update (version 2)

Comment: Did you give it time to actually be distributed to the download servers?  Are you getting the new version (checking the version of the app in settingss)?

Comment: i only use the apk files, the mp3 files in apk. then upload new apk release to play store